# common directory used by all users in Linux and track updates

Tags: linux, permissions

I want to create common directory used by all users in Linux.

I am using SLES 11.

I want to create a shared folder for project code, if any user updates any files in directory I want to keep track of who has updated the file?

e.g 
/home/share

-rwxrwxrwx 1 priyanka project 8 Apr  2 10:54 test2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root     root      33 Apr  2 11:10 test

suppose user xxx updates file test2
it should change its owner to xxx

-rwxrwxrwx 1 xxx project 8 Apr  2 10:54 test2

Answer (score 2):

You can not solve this with a simple (built in) command or a script (that I know of). You can do this in C using inotify. [Here is a nice tutorialfrom IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html?ca=drs-).